# Handling pipes in C to create a shell

Tags: c, shell, pipe

```
cat file.txt | grep hello
```

The way I see this is that `cat file.txt` is executed and whatever is passed to the stdout is passed as input in a pipe to `grep hello`. Then `grep hello` finds all the occurrences that match `hello` in the given input.

Here is my confusion: does `grep hello` write back to the pipe so the parent process outputs whatever is in stdout? Or does `grep hello` put its returned content in stdout? How does it work?

I am asking this question because I am writing a shell in C.

Comment: This is not C at all.

Comment: Do you want to do this inside a C program or are you talking about things like the [C shell](https://www.cs.duke.edu/csl/docs/csh.html)?

Comment: Oh way, sorry. I forgot to specify I am writing a shell  in C.

Comment: `cat` writes to `stdout` which has been redirected. `grep` writes to `stdout` which has not been redirected.

Comment: First thing you'll have to do is write a parser, then, which is going to be a lot of work. Then you'll need to split up your statements into components and arrange the pipes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat`'s stdout is connected to `grep`'s stdin. `grep`'s stdout is connected to the default location, probably the terminal. `grep` doesn't feed its output back to `cat` -- the pipe is unidirectional.

Comment: ...mmm, so why is the output of cat file1.txt not shown when we execute  cat file1.txt | file2.txt. Does it happen because cat file.txt doesn't write to stdout but to one of the ends of the pipe which is a file descriptor, you are saying that cat's stdout is connect to grep's stdin, but they are both connected to the same stdin.

Comment: I think my above comment is wrong because after the pipe is seen, a new process is created, so they don't share the same stdin. The way I think this works, elaborating on what @John Kugelman says is that  file.txt doesn't write to stdout but to one of the ends of the pipe which is a file descriptor and then the FD of stdin "in the child process" is set to the file descriptor of the other end of the pipe and then grep hello is executed.